# HereMaps Vue: trying to add behavior but H.mapevents is undefined

Tags: vue.js, here-api

I am trying just a basic map with zoom behavior.
The Map itself works but I cannot add a behavior:

In my mounted for the map I am doing this:

```
let map = new H.Map(
        this.$refs.map,
        this.platform.createDefaultLayers().normal.map,
        {
          zoom: 10,
          center: {
            lng: pos.coords.longitude,
            lat: pos.coords.latitude
          }
        }
      );

      var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

      this.map = map;
```

At `var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));`

I get an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Behavior' of undefined
When I Debug it the H Object does not have the mapevents object in it.
Am I missing something?

Comment: I cannot import the H object; I have added the CDN. Is there something specific you did to import this library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you included/imported `'here-js-api/scripts/mapsjs-mapevents'` ?
Or how do you include/import `here-js`?

Comment: Thats it, didnt find that in the tutorial, after adding the files it worked !

Comment: Nice to hear that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import `mapevents.js`

```
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"
 type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

The complete import section should look like these:

```
 <html>
  <head>
  ...
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width"/>
  <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"
     type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"
     type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"
     type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  ...
  </head>
```

All the details can be found here

https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/events.html

Comment: Thank you for that. For whatever reason, this mapevents.js script is never mentioned in any of the official HERE Maps tutorials.

Comment: that is exactly the reason I provided the information ;-)